# how to know hashing algortihm from string

Tags: hash, cryptography

Let's assume I have a string like A2E8609807F05ADCCF127D9FB376ACCD and I think it is a hashed or crypto value. How can we check its hashing type is there any way ? Is there any website that check it or has a lot of hashing values ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string is created from a secure cryptographic hash function, there is no way to determine the algorithm that was used to hash it.  That's because the output of a secure hash function is indistinguishable from random, so you cannot actually tell if it was produced by a hash function at all.

For example, if I tell you that one of these outputs was produced by SHA-256 and the other by BLAKE2b-256, you cannot know the difference unless you can guess the input (which in this case, I have made easy):

```
ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad
bddd813c634239723171ef3fee98579b94964e3bb1cb3e427262c8c068d52319
```

You can guess in some cases what hash function might have been used if you know the length.  For example, a 256-bit input must have come from a hash function that was 256 bits in length, or one that was longer and truncated.  But it could also have just come from a CSPRNG as well.

If your goal is to see if the hash value is one of a common input for a common function, there are some websites that will do that.  For example, [this website](https://md5.gromweb.com/) will look up an MD5 hash if it's of a common input, but if it's of a high-entropy input, it will be computationally infeasible to find.  Note also that MD5 is insecure and should not be used.